I'm unable to add role assignments



I don't know how to solve this:

The client 'live.com#xxxxxxx@gmail.com' with object id 'xxxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Authorization/classicadministrators/read' over scope '/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials


To add role assignment,  You should have Azure built-in Role of Owner role or User Access Administrator role at Subscription level

You should mask/hide any personal or sensitive information contained in your screenshots such as email address, subscription ID, etc.

ERROR:

The client 'live.com#xxxxxxx@gmail.com' with object id 'xxxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Authorization/classicadministrators/read' over scope '/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials

The ERROR occours when you do not have privilege. To assign RBAC roles, you need to have either User Access Administrator or Owner role that includes below permission: Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/write
You can check your access/ Current role assignments
Navigate to your Azure portal

Privileged administrator roles are those that give users elevated access, such as managing Azure resources or assigning roles to others.
These roles provide higher-level permissions and apply to all types of resources within Azure.

Know more about privileged administrator role assignment
